# Inserting CRS definition using insert expression in print composer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I'm still new in using QGIS

QGIS version: 2.16.2 64x

I don't know what will i enter in the "insert expression" so that the CRS definition will be the one to show in the label box

i tried the example below: 
layer_property('i input the name of the layer','crs_definition')
but nothing showed after i click ok[image]

Comment: Works ok for me - are you sure the layer name is correct (and unique)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested the expression in both QGIS 2.14.7 and 2.16.3 and both works. I don't know why the expression didn't work with you, but you should enter the following expression:

```
layer_property( 'LayerName','crs_definition')
```

[image]

The output will look like this in the `Label` menu located at the `Item Property` and in the text label:

[image]

[image]